# What does the declarations {sa_family=AF_UNIX} and [110->2] mean in accept4?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I did an strace in my android and I got the following line

`accept4(8<UNIX:[246]>, {sa_family=AF_UNIX}, [110->2], 0) = 9<UNIX:[2512219]>`

I don't understand what {sa_family=AF_UNIX} does (it should be a sockaddr pointer but where does it points to in terms of path and memory address?) and I want to know what the 110 and the 2 means and why 110 is pointing to 2 and what exactly is returned from this operation.

(I'm really curious about the peer of a socket created like this because I can't find the inode 2512219 in any of the proc/PID/fd files so I wonder if the process which has read/write the socket is dead by now and if I can get his name.) Thanks!

Comment: How is this related to the C programing language? Maybe it is a pre-processor, framework, something else, but it definitely doesn't look like C. I think you should choose a more suitable  tag.

Comment: sorry, but the {sa_family=AF_UNIX} is supossed to be a pointer to a structure that to me seems to be programmed in C, can you tell me in which language the sockaddr structure is implemented?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but the tag "c" is definitely not suitable. Please update the question and provide the details of your project. Android? Windows? *nix? where did you find that line? A framework? Which? On the internet? Please provide link.

Comment: These are not declarations. Starce doesn't print declarations, in C or otherwise. It prints traces of system calls.

Comment: the first line of the description "I did an strace in my android" should be clear to those who have some experience with the linux-kernel that I got a log in verbose of the system calls of a process in my android phone. That line comes from strace command. I don't see how can I make it more clear

Comment: What strace options did you use?

Comment: @n.m. Yes the system calls often have parameters, so strace displays a lot of them. In the case it displays the parameter {sa_family=AF_UNIX} which is not trivial and I want to understand what it means

Comment: @KamilCuk -f -p -y -yy

Comment: It means that the parameter is a struct with a field named `sa_family` set to `AF_UNIX`. `man strace` says *structures are annotated using curly braces* so you might want to peruse it.

Comment: @n.m. it does not have a path tho I wonder what it means, where is the peer for the socket. I will look for the man strace to see if i can find the meaning to [110->2]

Comment: `-f -p -y -yy` will give `strace: Invalid process id: '-y'`, from `strace -h`: `-p pid         trace process with process id PID`

Comment: It means "was 110, became 2". Which also explains why there's no path. *When the address of an unnamed socket is returned by getsockname(2), getpeername(2), and accept(2), its length is sizeof(sa_family_t), and sun_path should not be inspected* (man unix 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man accept4](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> int accept4(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr,
>                      socklen_t *addrlen, int flags);

```
accept4(8<UNIX:[246]>, {sa_family=AF_UNIX}, [110->2], 0) = 9<UNIX:[2512219]>
```

- `8` is `sockfd` value. From man: `the listening socket, sockfd`
- `246` is the inode number of `8` file descriptor
- The struct member `.sa_family` in the structure `struct sockaddr` stored in memory pointed to by the pointer `addr` has the value of `AF_UNIX`
- From man: `[addr] It is filled in with the address of the peer socket, as known to the  communications  layer`.
- `110` input value `addrlen` (the `socklen_t` integer stored in the memory pointed to by `addrlen` pointer). From man: `the caller  must  initialize  it [addrlen] to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by addr;`
- `2` value of `addrlen` after the function returned. From man: `will contain the actual size of the peer address`.
- `0` flags `flags`. From man: `If  flags  is 0, then accept4() is the same as accept().`
- `9` returned file descriptor. From man: `a nonnegative integer that  is  a file descriptor for the accepted socket`
- `2512219` inode number of `9`th file descriptor